# Hibernate merge non-managed entity with managed entity

Tags: java, mysql, performance, hibernate

I need to get data from a query, this retrieve id of Entity A, Entity B and Entity C  also tree custom fields. Something like this

```
SELECT
  a.id_entityA,
  b.id_entityB, 
  c.id_entityC, 
  sum(some) * sum(another),
  avg(of_some) * any_factor,
  another_operations,
From ... Many Selects, joins, etc
```

This retrieve info like

```
54 | 80 | 60 | 5421 | 56474.4 | 4540
```

In hibernate, I create a SQLQuery to get info in a DTO

```
public class ExampleDTO {
  private Integer idA;
  private Integer idB;
  private Integer idC;

  private Number fieldX;
  private Number fieldY;
  private Number fieldZ;

  //getters and settters 
}
```

In query execute I add the resultTransformer

```
.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(ExampleDTO.class))
```

And works!!!

But, I need another fields of Entity A, B and C,

```
public class ExampleDTO {
 // bottom of fields
  private EntityA entityA;
  private EntityB entityB;
  private EntityC entityC;
 // news and olds getters and setters
```

So i read this in a bucle to fill

```
for(ExampleDTO e : list)
{
   e.setEntityA(entityADao.getById(e.getIdA());
   e.setEntityB(entityBDao.getById(e.getIdB());
   e.setEntityC(entityCDao.getById(e.getIdC());
}
```

Works but its **old fashioned low performance** way to get data.

There are some *magical* way to get the three entities in the same query, to only have to run the first query and do **NOT** bluce to fill my list of dto

*edit*
suppose that `EntityA`, `EntityB` and `EntityC`, are anoted with `@Entity`

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly what you're trying to do, you want to run a single query to get three entities and also run SQL commands to perform math, all in a single query.  The last time I worked with Hibernate, I believe it wasn't possible to do arbitrary SQL formulas within HQL or Criteria/getById(); that is, you had to pick whether to run SQL, or have Hibernate do its ORM magic, but couldn't do both at once.  But that may no longer be accurate...

Answer (score 0):

There is no magical way to have aggregated projections and fetched entities. You'd have to manually include all fetched entities properties in the group by clause anyway.

If the entities are unrelated you will end up with a Cartesian product, which is even more trouble.

My suggestion is to run the projection query and get those ids and make use of 2nd level cache to optimize the additional entity retrieval (but not through running a query, which will by-pass the second level cache) when finding the entities:

```
session.get(EntityA.class, 1L); 
session.get(EntityB.class, 1L);
session.get(EntityC.class, 1L);
```

If the entities are related, you can try to use a second join query to select some/all entities but that will require having all those entities referencing one another.